# CefSharp Sharing Session Cookies c#

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I built a App (CefSharp Browser) and I'm trying to share login Session cookies, But when I open the App on another device, the cookies don't work.. and it asks to log in again.
What I want to do is share cookies without revealing my password .. When the cookies expire I renew them again and so on.

This is what I have done so far.. I created a folder (Temp) to save cookies on disk only for testing

```
        var path = "C:\\";
        var folder = Path.Combine(path, "Temp");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

Then I created a cookie path

```
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();        
        string path1 = "C:\\Temp\\";
        settings.CachePath = path1;
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

and then

```
        ِC1 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://subscene.com/");
        Panel1.Controls.Add(C1);
        C1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

When I transfer Temp folder cookie to another device, it does not work ...
I don't know the correct way to share cookies.. And I really need it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons cookies are encrypted in Chromium. On Windows DPAPI is used.

> As part of the goal of protecting private user information, this encrypts the cookie values on operating systems with user-specific crypto APIs and that do not otherwise protect this data

As per https://codereview.chromium.org/24734007

Cookies cannot be read on a different device for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.